# In NestJS with TypeORM(MySQL), how do you typically write Entity files?

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Assuming there is an Entity file named "TestEntity". Here is the example code.

```
@Entity({ name: 'Test' })
export class TestEntity {
   @Column('varchar', { nullable: true })
   temp?: string;   // ---> (1)
   temp!: string | null;  // ---> (2)
}
```

In the TestEntity, there is a column named 'temp', and this column allows null values. Do you prefer to write the column name and type in the style of (1) or (2)? Additionally, could you please briefly explain the reason for your choice? Since responses from developers can vary in community forums and blog posts, I wanted to ask this question.

Have a great day!

I tested using the first method. However, when trying to update a row in the database with a 'temp' column to NULL, I encountered an error due to a type mismatch between NULL and undefined.